# Graceful exit from BlockingCollection.TakeFromAny when adding to collections completed

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

I wait for available items in two `BlockingCollections` in a loop using `BlockingCollection.TakeFromAny`. Items are added to the collections in other theads. At some point I finish adding to the collections and on the next call to `TakeFromAny` my code gets stuck and does not return from it.

I tried to use `CompleteAdding` for the two collections or use `TakeFromAny` with a `CancellationToken` parameter but in both cases an exception occurs:

- with `CompleteAdding` there is an `ArgumentException` with the message

> All collections are marked as complete with regards to additions. Parameter name: collections

- with `CancellationToken` there is an `OperationCanceledException` obviously.

Is it possible to set collections in some way that my code gets out from TakeFromAny without an exception and with a return value that would indicate that there won't be any new items in the underlying collections?

`TryTakeFromAny` is not suitable for my needs as it always returns when it happens that the collections are currently empty but items still will be added later. I want to block until the next item is available or there is nothing to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `TryTakeFromAny` is not suitable for my needs as it always returns when it happens that the collections are currently empty but items still will be added later. I want to block until the next item is available or there is nothing to add.

The `TryTakeFromAny()` method has overloads that allow you to specify a timeout value. The method will not return until either there's a value to be returned, or the timeout period has been exceeded.

For these overloads, if you specify a timeout of -1 milliseconds, the method will wait indefinitely. It will not throw an exception if either collection has had its `CompleteAdding()` method called, and it will return `-1` as the collection index value if all of the collections passed to it have had their `CompleteAdding()` method called.

A simple example that shows this working:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BlockingCollection<int> c1 = new BlockingCollection<int>(), c2 = new BlockingCollection<int>();

    Task task = Produce(c1, c2);

    while (BlockingCollection<int>.TryTakeFromAny(new[] { c1, c2 }, out int value, -1) >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"value: {value}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"task.IsCompleted: {task.IsCompleted}");
    task.Wait();
}

private static async Task Produce(BlockingCollection<int> c1, BlockingCollection<int> c2)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    c1.Add(1);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    c1.CompleteAdding();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    c2.Add(2);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    c2.CompleteAdding();
}
```